# Start cnosdb repeatedly, cnosdb may panics

Tags: cnosdb

Start cnosdb repeatedly, cnosdb may panics
version:cnosdb 2.3.3, revision d86358a6fc813f4b83b36f0005448e7140a2d4e0

```
2023-10-25T10:34:59.576844000+08:00 DEBUG cnosdb::meta_single::meta_service: watch.1001 17.17: change logs: WatchData { full_sync: false, min_ver: 15, max_ver: 17, entry_logs: [] } 
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: MetaClientErr { msg: "NetworkError: reqwest::error::Error: error sending request for url (http://127.0.0.1:8901/write): connection error: Connection reset by peer (os error 54) source: connection error: Connection reset by peer (os error 54) source: Connection reset by peer (os error 54)" }
Location: main/src/server.rs:188

  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ BACKTRACE ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
                                ⋮ 10 frames hidden ⋮                              
  11: cnosdb::server::ServiceBuilder::build_query_storage::{{closure}}::h18bc817435fd5030
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  12: cnosdb::main::{{closure}}::hc53e26088ca8ad83
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  13: cnosdb::main::h8b6b5feb807acbf4
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  14: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::heaff541c935b36c6
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  15: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}::h221f8e367097f1d8
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  16: std::rt::lang_start_internal::h672762ded3eb0218
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  17: _main<unknown>
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>

Run with COLORBT_SHOW_HIDDEN=1 environment variable to disable frame filtering.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
```

./targetrelease/cnosdb run --config ./config/config_8902.toml -M singleton

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the fact that the kv and query modules for cnosdb are started, but the meta module is not